# jQuery - Call Function After

Tags: jquery

I'm having an issue at the moment which is causing me some headache.

using .ajax / php I pull a option list back into a div that I have created.

Basically a user uses the first dropdown box and selects a car make a second dropdown box appears with the .ajax query models.

When someone then selects their car model I want it to alert the user which model they have selected.

I'm having trouble because I'm already calling the alert function before the injection of  has been pulled through.

Hope that makes sense, here is my current code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.model_id').change(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: 'http://mydomain.net/getmodel.php',
            data: { make_id: $('.model_id').val() },
            datatype: "html",
            success:function(data){
                $('.result').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
  });

$(success).load(function(){
  $('.result').change(function() {
        alert('s');
    });
  });

</script>
```

Comment: What is $(success) selecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
 $(success).load(function(){
  $('.result').change(function() {
        alert('s');
    });
  });
```

to

```
$('.result').change(function() {
        alert('s');
    });
```

(i.e. remove the $(success) part)

Answer (score 0):

Why not doing something like :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var old_data = '';

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.model_id').change(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: 'http://mydomain.net/getmodel.php',
            data: { make_id: $('.model_id').val() },
            datatype: "html",
            success:function(data){
                if ( old_data != data )
                    alert(data);

                old_data = data;
                $('.result').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
  });

</script>
```

Comment: Hi Cosmin,

Thanks for the reply!

I think you have got it a little mixed up, I want an alert to show when someone changes the 2nd dropdown box that I generate with the first query...

Answer (score 0):

use `live` for such kind of operations:

```
$('.result').live('change',function() {
    alert('s');
});
```

Comment: He doesn't need live as he is not adding and removing .result from the DOM, only its contents.  Also, live is being deprecated.  You should use .on in the future.